# How can I set expiry on Second Level Cache?

Tags: java, spring-boot, second-level-cache, ehcache-3

### Problem

I can't set expiry of second level cache with Ehcache.
Is there any way to config expiry?

### My Codes

#### build.gradle

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-jcache:5.6.5.Final'
implementation 'org.ehcache:ehcache:3.9.9'
```

#### application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  jpa:

    properties:
      javax:
        persistence:
          sharedCache:
            mode: ENABLE_SELECTIVE   # Enable caches only @Cacheable annotated classes
      hibernate:
        cache:
          use_query_cache: true
          use_second_level_cache: true
          region:
            factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory
```

#### My Entity

```kotlin
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Entity
@Cacheable
@Cache(region = "test_cache", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Test {
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

1. Change your `factory_class` to `org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory`
2. Create an `ehcache.xml` in `/src/main/resources` with this content:

```
   ...
   <cache-template name="default">
      <expiry>
         <ttl unit="hours">48</ttl>
      </expiry>
    </cache-template>
   ...
```

Details to the XML configuration can be found at https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.9/xml.html

Comment: Thank you for answering!  
But I have another question.  
Should I decrease my EhCache Version? Is there any other way?

Comment: I would use the latest release. That's 3.9.6.

Comment: Oh I took some mistake. 
Thank you!